# Angular Pagination, Get Current Page number

Tags: javascript, pagination, angular8

I am trying to get current page in pagination. This the code in app.component.html:

```
<ngb-pagination  [collectionSize]="500" [(page)]="page" (click)="showPageIndex(page)" aria-label="Default pagination" ></ngb-pagination>

<p>current page is {{page}}</p>
```

in app.component.ts:

```
public page = 1;


   showPageIndex(pageIndex){
     this.page = pageIndex;
     console.log(this.page);
   }
```

When I click on the page (say page 12), I am getting the result as '1'. When, I click again, I am getting the result as '12' (correct one).

However,

current page is {{page}}

, is displaying the correct page.

It seems that when the onclick is triggered, it gets the value of the current page (not the one after the click is done).

Is something wrong with this approach? Should, I write the code for pagination manually in this case, instead of using a library?

Appreciate your support.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using (pageChange)="onPageChange(currentPage), instead of (click)